# How to get template link?

Tags: page-template, links

If I create template-portfolio, how do I get the link of this template? Like:

```
<a href="<?php the_link"> View portfolios </a>
```

What would be the function or link here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using that template for only one page, you can try this function:

```
/**
 * @param  string  $template  Base name of the template.
 */
function wpse_233924_get_page_link($template)
{
    $query = new \WP_Query;

    // Get page which is using the $template.
    $page = $query->query([
      'post_type'      => 'page',
      'meta_key'       => '_wp_page_template',
      'meta_value'     => $template,
      'no_found_rows'  => 1,
      'posts_per_page' => 1 // Retrieve only one result.
    ]);

    return isset($page[0]) ? esc_url( get_page_link($page[0]) ) : false;
}
```

Then:

```
$page_url = wpse_233924_get_page_link('template-portfolio.php') ? : '#';

?><a href="<?= $page_url ?>">View portfolios</a><?php
```

Note that WordPress recognizes `page-templates` folder by default. So, if you put the `template-porfolio.php` inside that folder, the value of `$template` must be `page-templates/template-portfolio.php`.

Comment: [code] <?php $page_url = wpse_233924_get_page_link('template-testimonials.php') ? : '#';?>

<a href="<?php $page_url ?>">View portfolios</a>  [/code] is not working, any ideas

Comment: @Droidriddhi Did it work for `template-portfolio.php`? If not, I have no ideas.

Comment: no, it is showing localhost/wordpress1 link only

Comment: if i hover on view portfolio it showing only only localhost/wordpress1 address